# RestTemplate getForObject to POJO

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I'm using `RestTemplate.getForObject()` to retrieve json that includes a couple of objects and arrays, I only want to convert one of the objects inside this json to a POJO, I don't care about the other objects inside this json.

What is the proper way to approach this?

---

Edit:

Another approach from accepted answer, we can use jacksons `ObjectMapper`

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper;
```

then

```
LinkedHashMap obj1 = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, LinkedHashMap.class, params);
LinkedHashMap obj2 = (LinkedHashMap)test.get("flightStatuses");

Flight flight = jacksonObjectMapper.convertValue(obj2, Flight.class);
```

You get the idea, just get a generic datatype from your json structure then use `ObjectMapper` to convert it to the class you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to create a wrapper class, which includes the POJO you want to deserialize and ignore all other properties using `@JsonIgnoreProperties`. You would then retrieve the wrapper object and get the POJO from it.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class Wrapper {
     private MyPojo myPojo;
}

MyPojo myPojo = restTemplate.getForObject("url", Wrapper.class).getMyPojo();
```

Comment: Good idea, thanks. I've also figured out another way that doesn't require a an extra class. Check edit.